# Find the image of this complex fractional function.

Tags: complex-analysis

There is a question but no solution in my lecture's note. There was only answer in his note.

$Q)$ Find the image $T(D) $ for $T(z) = -\frac{2iz}{z-1}$ for $z \in D (=\{ z \in \mathbb{C} \vert Re(z) \geq 0\})$

---

My attempt)  Put $w = x+iy \in  T(D)$, then $w = \frac {-2iz}{z-1}$. So we can conclude $z = \frac{w}
{w+2i}$

Therefore, $z= \frac{x+iy}{x+i(y+2)} \Rightarrow Re(z) = \frac {x^2 + y(y+2)}{x^2+(y+2)^2} \geq0$

The answer is $x^2 + y(y+2) \geq 0$ (I.e. Outside of the circle $x^2 + (y+1)^2 \geq 1$)

But the answer was $T(D) = \{z = x+iy \in \mathbb{C} \vert (x-1)^2 + y^2 \leq 1 \}$

What the point did I mistake? Still I don't know which point I wrong. Or Is his answer incorrect?

Thanks.

Comment: By a numerical plot it looks as if your answer is correct (and the one in the note wrong).

Comment: This might help:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation#Determining_the_fixed_points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that $$T(0)= 0 \\ T(i) = -1-i\\ T(-i) = 1-i .$$This implies that $T$ takes the generalised circle $\{z: Re(z) = 0\}$ to the circle $\{z: |z+i| = 1\}$. Now note that, $T(2) = -4i \in \{z: |z+i|>1\}$.

Therefore, by connectedness, $T(D) = \{z:|z+i|\geq 1\}$.

So, his answer is incorrect, you are right.